# History of the method of adding and subtracting the same number

Tags: math-history

We know that when a number is added and subtracted, the effect is null (same number of course).

I want to know the first occurrence of this documented method. Is it from Euclid's elements in Book $5$?

> the relationships of equivalence and of excess are compatible with addition and subtraction in the sense that if equivalent magnitudes are added to (or taken from) 
>   each of two others, the resulting magnitudes will be in the same relation as the 
>   originals.

[Source](http://www.lamath.org/journal/vol5no2/Ratio_Proportion.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book V of Euclid's Elements deals not with number, but with *ratio* between magnitudes.

The interpretative issues are thorny; see :

> Jacob Klein, *Greek Mathematical Thought and the Origins of Algebra*, German original ed 1936 (Dover reprint)
>
> Wilbur R. Knorr, *The Evolution of the Euclidean Elements*, 1975
>
> Ian Mueller, *Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid’s Elements*, 1981 (Dover reprint)
>
> Ivor Grattan-Guinness, *Numbers, Magnitudes, Ratios, and Proportions in Euclid’s Elements*, 1996 in *Historia Mathematica*.

Magnitudes for Euclid are not numbers; for ancient Greeks, numbers are (our) natural numbers.

Lenght and area are magnitudes. The discovery of the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ forced ancient Greek mathematics to leave the Pythagorean "axiom" that every natural phenomenon can be described with (natural) numbers : the diagonal of the unit square cannot.